# Import Yeoman/Angularjs application

Tags: css, angularjs, less

I have been trying to search for an answer to this but not really know what to search for. I would like to know if there is any way I can create a "component" in AngularJS that contains directives, css etc and use that component in another project?

For example, I would like to create an angularjs application that contains our companys base layout defined in css/less and also a toolbox of customized controls/directives. I would then like to create a new application in AngularJS and import the "base" application.

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, what you need to do is take all the directives, controllers, services, etc that you want to share, move them into a separate folder, and place them all under a single namespace.

Then, to reuse that component in another angular application, you simply have to reference those JS/CSS files as normal, and make sure to declare that project as a dependency when setting up Angular.

That's essentially it -- Angular makes it very easy for you to declare dependencies and reuse code. There's nothing really special you need to do.

If you want, you can also try managing and distributing your custom component using Bower (though if this is company code, that may not be an option, depending on your setup). If so, [this link](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-bower) contains more detailed information on how to do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very helpful. We actually have bower repository at our head office so we look at using that.